# IBM MQ Windows Client C# tring to connect to server fails with 2298 error

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

i am new in MQ, but have to make an Application for my company. I need to get Messages in C# from an MessageQueue, i tried the example SimpleGet.cs, which was in the 8.0.0.10 Windows 64bit client sample folder. I can reach the point where it tries to connect to the QueueMessenger, where it throws the 2298 error.

```
 Console.Write("Connecting to queue manager.. ");
                queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, properties);
```

The error message is:

> ```
> MQException caught: 2298 - 2298    bei
> IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager.Connect(String queueManagerName)    bei
> IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager..ctor(String queueManagerName, Hashtable
> properties)    bei SimpleGet.SimpleGet.GetMessages() in C:\Program
> Files\IBM\WebSphere
> MQ\Tools\dotnet\samples\cs\base\SimpleGet\SimpleGet.cs:Zeile 318.
> ```

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the `SimpleGet`?  For example `SimpleGet -q queueName -h host -p port -l channel`

Comment: I have the project open in visual Studio and im setting the parameter there. And i am pretty shure the connection data is write

Comment: Can you provide what parameters you are setting?

Comment: i am setting queue-manager, host, port, channel and queue-name

Comment: could it be a problem that i try to connect to an 5.3 Server ?

Comment: It could be.  What does the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG show at the same time?    Can you try with 8.0.0.9?

Answer (score 1):

**Working for .Net 6.0 (IBM MQ 9 Client)**

If you are using IBM MQ Dotnet Client ver 9 or above then you need to set MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED for the MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY instead of MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT as seen below:

```
connectionProperties = new Hashtable()
    {
        { MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED },
        { MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName },
        { MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port },
        { MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel },
        { MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR },
        { MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, user },
        { MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password }
    };
```

Comment: Thnx, this worked for me. I removed the last two lines as the current user (used to launch the program) had the right credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by installing a newer version of MQ(8.0.0.10) now it is working

Comment: Can you update this to reflect what version you updated to?

Comment: In your original question you stated "which was in the 8.0.0.10 Windows 64bit client sample folder.", but in your answer you said you fixed it by "installing a newer version of MQ(8.0.0.10)".  So what was actually done to fix the issue?

Comment: i had a 5.* Server to test my things, then i installed a mq 8.0.0.10 Server and now it is working